# Converting string in to dateformat

Tags: javascript

How can i convert this data in to appropriate date format

today 09:48 am.

yesterday 05:58 pm.

Monday 03:17 PM.

Friday 06:15 PM.

Friday 03:42 PM.

Thursday 07:27 PM.

08/Dec/10 05:05 PM

Thanks in advance 
Joseph

Answer (score 1):

You can't - not easily. For example, does Monday refer to last Monday, today (if today is Monday), or next Monday?
Assuming today is Sunday (I'm guessing your dates are going backwards chronologically) then you'd want to do something like this (my Javascript is rusty by the way, so YMMV):

```
var thisDate = "today 9:48 am";
bool isAm = (thisDate.indexOf("am") >= 0);
var todayDate = new Date();
thisDate.replace("today", todayDate);
thisDate.replace("yesterday", todayDate.getDate()-1);
```

You'd then want to do parsing to calculate the day of the week and subtract accordingly with day names.
However, **get the key logic right first** - what does Monday refer to?

HTH,

Benjamin